# Bash - changing fileconfig format

Tags: scripting, text-formatting, freeradius

I would like to change:

**THIS:**

```
client 192.168.100.1 {
    secret = ThisIStheSECRET
    shortname = HOSTNAME
}
client 192.168.100.2 {
    secret = ThisIStheSECRET2
    shortname = HOSTNAME2
}
```

**THAT:**

```
client HOSTNAME { secret = ThisIStheSECRET, ipaddr = 192.168.100.1 }
client HOSTNAME2 { secret = ThisIStheSECRET2, ipaddr = 192.168.100.2 }
```

How to do this? What tools to use?

Comment: I hope the secret can never contain a comma.

Comment: I checked this right now - none of the 10k declarations in file doesn't contains a comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straight-forward `awk` script:

```
awk '
    /^client/               { ipaddr    = $2                              }
    /^[[:blank:]]*shortname/{ shortname = $3                              }
    /^[[:blank:]]*secret/   { secret    = $0; sub("^[^=]*= ", "", secret) }
    /^}/ {
        printf("client %s { secret = %s, ipaddr = %s }\n",
            shortname, secret, ipaddr);
    }' file
```

Simply parse out the needed bits of information when we find them in the input file, and when we hit a `}` at the start of a line, we output the gathered information in the correct format.

The parsing of the `secret` text is special since we're expecting it to contain *anything*, even field delimiters. It simply starts by setting the variable `secret` to the whole line and then deletes everything up to the first `=` and the single space thereafter.

Given the file

```
client 192.168.100.2 {
    secret = ThisIStheSECRET2
    shortname = HOSTNAME2
}
client 10.0.0.1 {
    secret =     This is it, the secret!, ipaddr = 10.0.0.1
    shortname = myhost.local
}
```

(notice four spaces at the start of the secret), this produces

```
client HOSTNAME2 { secret = ThisIStheSECRET2, ipaddr = 192.168.100.2 }
client myhost.local { secret =     This is it, the secret!, ipaddr = 10.0.0.1, ipaddr = 10.0.0.1 }
```

Comment: I definitely need to get more familiar with awk.

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your issue, although wasn't as "simple" as I was hoping for:

```
perl -pe 's/(\w)\s*$/\1,\n/;' your_filename | perl -pe 'BEGIN{undef $/;} s/(?<!})\s*\n\s*/ /smg;' -e 's/(client )(\S+)(.*?)(\w+),\s*}/\1\4\3\2 }/g;'
```

It runs one regular expression to add commas you your lines ending with alphanumerics (A to Z, a to z, 0 to 9, and _)

It runs another regular expression to replace any newlines (and the whitespace surrounding them) by one space, unless that line ends in a `}` (utilizing a negative look-behind), then finally a regex for final formatting (switch hostname and IP and remove extraneous comma)

This ignores newlines, and you can redirect the result into a new file (or your existing one) with `> your_new_filename` added to the end. This solution could use a `-i` flag to have it to modify your file in place if you instead did this:

```
perl -i -pe 's/(\w)\s*$/\1,\n/;' your_filename
perl -i -pe 'BEGIN{undef $/;} s/(?<!})\s*\n\s*/ /smg;' -e 's/(client )(\S+)(.*?)(\w+),\s*}/\1\4\3\2 }/g;' your_filename
```

Comment: Oh, I missed the comma between lines. I'll edit

Comment: The output is:
`client 192.168.100.1 { secret = ThisIStheSECRET, short = HOSTNAME }`

Instead of:
`client HOSTNAME { secret = ThisIStheSECRET, ipaddr = 192.168.100.1 }`

@cunninghamp3 Could You edit Your answer?

Comment: Full Script changing declarations in clients.conf (From freeradius 2.0 to 3.0 format) will be:

grep -v "#" /etc/freeradius/3.0/clients.conf | grep -v ipaddr | grep . | perl -p -e 's/(\w)\s*$/\1,\n/;' | perl -pe 'BEGIN{undef $/;} s/(?<!})\s*\n\s*/ /smg;' -e 's/,\s*}/ }/g' | awk '{ print $1" "$9" "$3" "$4" = "$6" ipaddr = "$2" "$10}'

Comment: @Mario_bash, I guess my reading comprehension is at an all time low this morning. See my update.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are better ways to address this, but I achieved it with the following `sed`, `awk` combination.

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' file | sed -e 's/    //g' -e 's/ client/\nclient/' | awk '{print $1" "$9" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6",  ipaddress "$8" "$2" "$10}'
```

Explanation

- `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'` To replace all new lines with a space. Refer to this [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed#answer-1252191) for more information
- `sed -e 's/    //g'` To replace the four spaced blocks with a single space.
- `-e 's/ client/\nclient/'` Add the new line when the client string matches.
- `awk '{print $1" "$9" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6",  ipaddress "$8" "$2" "$10}'` Awk by default delimits the text with spaces, so in here you only need to print the hostname variable ($9) and the ip address variable ($2) in the order you want. You can dismiss the "shortname" variable ($7) and hardcode the ", ipaddress" text

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's{client\s+(\S+)\s*\{\s*(secret = .*)\s+shortname\s*=\s*(.*)\s*\}}
                 {client $3 { $2, ipaddr = $1 }}g'
```